# Inexpensive Two-factor authentication for a home server?

Tags: linux, encryption, one-time-password

I was considering adding some kind of two-factor authentication to my small home network of linux dedicated servers. I would need, maybe at absolute most, 10 physical devices. Are there any companies out there that would provide such a small order, for relatively cheap?

Thanks,
Daniel

PS This is mainly for my own enjoyment of setting up of a system; I do not claim to function highly at-risk machines.

Comment: I suppose that you need something that would be usable over the network, like the electronic tokens some banks provide? Or would a fingerprint scanner also qualify?

Comment: Belongs on http://serverfault.com

Comment: Can you use a smart-phone as such a physical device?

Answer (score 5):

Duo Security provides two-factor authentication for Unix systems: [duo_unix](https://github.com/duosecurity/duo_unix).  It is free for open source projects and installations with less than ten users.

Disclaimer, I am a Duo developer.

Comment: I'll endorse this, as a user who isn't affiliated with Duo in any way except as a customer. The only reason I might not recommend them for this specific use is that it's not much of a learning experience - you install the software and it Just Works. You'll learn more (but probably won't be as secure) rolling your own OTP system, so you might want to look at doing your own thing, but for production use Duo has a really nice, robust, easy system. Be really careful to set it up so it doesn't lock you out of console login if the network is down! (only apply to remote connections)

Answer (score 2):

Would you consider something like [OPIE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OPIE_Authentication_System)? (an S/KEY based OTP system).
You should be able to set PAM up to require both a password and the OTP value, and most smartphones can run a generator.